# How to format sql output into json

Tags: go

I have a Go function that queries a database and returns two columns:

```
var colA string
var colB string

    err = db.QueryRow("select colA, colB from table where colA = %v", 1).Scan(&colA,&colB)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(colA,colB)

    return nil
```

I would like to return the output in json format like {colA:colB}. I have played around with the json.Marshal function but can't get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a struct if you know what your data is going to be: e.g

```
type User struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
}
```

Then on your query:

```
user := User{}
err = db.QueryRow("select colA, colB from table where colA = %v", 1).Scan(&user.Username,&user.Email)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
}
```

Then call marshal on it

```
msg, err := json.Marshal(user)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(msg)) // "{ "username": "Blah", "email": "asd@asd.com" }"
```

Also with the `json.Marshal` package if you're calling `Marshal` on a `struct` your fields MUST be exported by using a capital first letter on the field name, e.g. `Username`

> // Field is ignored by this package. Field int `json:"-"`
>
> // Field appears in JSON as key "myName". Field int `json:"myName"`
>
> // Field appears in JSON as key "myName" and // the field is omitted
>   from the object if its value is empty, // as defined above. Field int
>   `json:"myName,omitempty"`
>
> // Field appears in JSON as key "Field" (the default), but // the
>   field is skipped if empty. // Note the leading comma. Field int
>   `json:",omitempty"`

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Answer (score 0):

You can create a one element map and marshal it:

```
m := map[string]string{colA: colB}
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
```

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/ntT5h3oHvY

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into some database management frameworks.

I personally use gorm (github.com/jinzhu/gorm) for my database needs. It has functionality for automatically creating your database using structs and parsing them back out again.

You can pair that with the "encoding/json" package to take it to/from json to/from your database.

Here's some personal code you can use for reference:

[Struct](https://github.com/Superordinate/kDaemon/blob/master/models/applications.go):

```
type Application struct {
  Id            int64           `json:"id"`
  UserID        int64           `sql:"not null;" json:"user_id"`
  Name          string          `sql:"size:255; not null; unique;" json:"name"`
  ExposedPorts  string          `json:"exposed_ports"` //docker
  DockerImage   string          `sql:"size:255; not null;" json:"docker_image"`
  Dependencies  string          `json:"dependencies"`  
  IsEnabled     bool            `sql:"default:true" json:"is_enabled"`
```

}

JSON:

```
func (a *Application) GetJSON() (string, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(a)
    if err != nil {
        logging.Log(err)
        return "",err;
    }
    return string(b),err;
}
```

[Database](https://github.com/Superordinate/kDaemon/blob/master/database/database.go)

```
    //Get application information
func GetApplication(id int64) (*models.Application, error) {
 app := &models.Application{}

 err := db.Where(&models.Application{Id: id}).First(&app).Error

 return app, err
}

func GetApplications() ([]models.Application, error) {
    //Returns a list of all applications 
    apps := []models.Application{}

    err := db.Find(&apps).Error

    return apps, err
}

//delete application from database
func DeleteApplication(id int64) (bool, error) {
    logging.Log("Deleting Application: ", id)

    app := models.Application{}

    err := db.Where(&models.Application{Id: id}).First(&app).Error 

    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    //  TODO: Check for auth
    //      Delete all containers

    //Delete application from database
    err = db.Delete(&app).Error

    if err != nil {
       return false, err
    }

    return true, err

}

//Update Application
func UpdateApplication(app *models.Application) (bool, error) {

    newapp := models.Application{}
    err := db.Where(&models.Application{Id: app.Id}).First(&newapp).Error 

    if err != nil {
       return false, err
    }

    err = db.Save(&app).Error

    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely sample:

`campaign.model.go`:

```golang
package models

import "database/sql"

// Campaign Model
type Campaign struct {
    CampaignId int `db:"campaign_id" json:"campaignId"`
    CampaignNme string `db:"campaign_nme" json:"campaignNme"`
    OrganizationId sql.NullInt64 `db:"organization_id" json:"organizationId"`
}
```

`campaign.repository.go`:

```golang
package repositories

import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "go-clean-arch/domain/models"
    "go-clean-arch/domain/repositories"
)

type CampaignRepository struct {
    Db *sqlx.DB
}

func NewCampaignRepository(Db *sqlx.DB) repositories.CampaignRepository {
    return &CampaignRepository{Db}
}

func (cr *CampaignRepository)FindById(id string) (models.Campaign, error) {
    campaign := models.Campaign{}
    query := `
        SELECT
            campaign_id,
            campaign_nme,
            organization_id
        FROM "CAMPAIGN" WHERE campaign_id = $1
    `
    err := cr.Db.Get(&campaign, query, id)
    if err != nil {
        return campaign, err
    }
    return campaign, nil
}
```

`main.go`:

```golang
func main() {
    dbConf := database.PGDatabaseConfig{
        Host: viper.GetString("SQL_HOST"),
        Port: viper.GetString("SQL_PORT"),
        User: viper.GetString("SQL_USER"),
        Password: viper.GetString("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        Dbname: viper.GetString("SQL_DB"),
    }
    db, err := database.ConnectPGDatabase(&dbConf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer func () {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    //userRepository := repositories.NewUserRepository(db)
    //users, _ := userRepository.FindAll()
    //fmt.Printf("%#v", &users)

    campaignRepository := repositories.NewCampaignRepository(db)
    campaign, err := campaignRepository.FindById("102")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", campaign)
    campaignJSON, err := json.Marshal(campaign)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(campaignJSON))

}
```

Output:

```sh
☁  go-clean-arch [master] ⚡  go run main.go
models.Campaign{CampaignId:102, CampaignNme:"Generic Party / Memories", OrganizationId:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}
campaignJSON: {"campaignId":102,"campaignNme":"Generic Party / Memories","organizationId":{"Int64":0,"Valid":false}}
```